# How to get equal width centered td?

Tags: html, html-table

Hi working to create a news letter template. At the moment I am stuck and can't get beyond created two `<td>` that have equal with and are centered.

Mind you this is for a newsletter template so since web 1998, most of the fancy web stuff is not usefull here!

I have attached a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/KOBepN), but below is the code! I need the two logos centered under the text. Any ideas?

```html
<table class="footertable" align="center" bgcolor="#e9eef2" width="900px">
  <tr>
    <td>
    
      <table style="height:100%;" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-size:14px;">
            Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://gdj.graphicdesignjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/best-logos-2017-37.jpg" alt="logo-small.png" width="90px">
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="https://www.prodesigns.com/backend/img/visual-brief/1497000058-alstrom.jpg" alt="noe-logo.png" width="90px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your table layout is invalid - you don't have equal amounts of columns in each row

Comment: add like this to `<td width="50%" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should let the td with the text span two column, and then center the image td-s. The 1998 way is using the center tag, but the modern way is using text-align: center. Here I use center for one of the images, and text-align for the other. I also added a border to make the table more visible, but the border should be removed.

```
  <table border="1" style="height:100%;" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p style="font-size:14px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <img src="http://gdj.graphicdesignjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/best-logos-2017-37.jpg" alt="logo-small.png" width="90px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center><img src="https://www.prodesigns.com/backend/img/visual-brief/1497000058-alstrom.jpg" alt="noe-logo.png" width="90px"></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need a **colspan** in first td see below code.

```html
<table class="footertable" align="center" bgcolor="#e9eef2" width="900px">
  <tr>
    <td>
    
      <table style="height:100%;" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p style="font-size:14px;">
            Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://gdj.graphicdesignjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/best-logos-2017-37.jpg" alt="logo-small.png" width="90px">
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="https://www.prodesigns.com/backend/img/visual-brief/1497000058-alstrom.jpg" alt="noe-logo.png" width="90px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the pointed out colspan, to center the contents of the cells with images, you'll need to add this styling to them:

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

Alternatively, you could set the images' style as:

```
style="display:block; margin:auto;"
```

I see you're referencing a class in the table tag - if you're indeed using a separate CSS sheet, it would be prudent to set these styles through the use of a class.